# Direct sum of a subspace and its orthogonal complement - proof

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

The proof below is from Sheldon Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Rights" (3rd. edition). I don't understand the marked step. I thought that the $v$ of the second inner product $<v, e_j>$ should actually be a $u$ and if not, why not?

Much appreciated if someone could elaborate!

[image]

Comment: $\langle \langle v, e_k \rangle e_k, e_j \rangle  =\langle v, e_k \rangle \langle e_k, e_j \rangle$ and $\langle e_k, e_j \rangle=0$ if $k \neq j$ , $1$ if $k=j$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!